# Mailchimp blocks sending mails after importing E-Mail addresses

Tags: email, mailchimp

My Mailchimp blocks sending the e-mails after I imported a larger number of e-mails.
I still have enough space of e-mails left but when I try sending the mail I get the following error:

```
List
MailChimp's artificial intelligence system, Omnivore, automatically scanned your recent import. Omnivore detected that abuse rates for the campaign will exceed industry thresholds. This needs to be resolved before we can support sending to this list.

To resolve this, we must ask that the list data be removed and reconfirmed through a verifiable process. Once this is done, the campaign can be replicated and resent.
```

But I can not resend to all my clients a subscriber link!
How can I solve this error so I can finally send e-mails again?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've alrady solved this, but if not, or anyone struggling with this...

I had the same problem. My solution (after contact with MailChimp support):

1. Delete all imported emails from the list.
2. Your Campaign probably still won't send, with same error, so:
3. Replicate the campaign. The new one will now be able to send.

This worked for me. If not for you, maybe the contact I had with the Compliance Team of Mailchimp was the solution and they confirmed my deleting of the emails. So email and stalk them.

The main issue for the blocking by Omnivore, was probably the amount of info@ and ofice@ addresses in the import list. At least delete ALL of those before import.

Cheers,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import a larget list of subscribers. I eventually figured out that I had to split the CSV file into **multiple CSV files with a maximum of 200 entries** (subscriber rows) in each for Omnivore to stop complaining.

[CSV Splitter](http://erdconcepts.com/download.html) (free Windows program) did the trick of splitting my large CSV into smaller chunks.

Before importing, I verified the email addreses in the subscriber list using [Free Email Verifier](http://freebulkemailverifier.com/homeFbulkev.php) (free online tool), as Omnivore might be cheching for non-existing email adresses.

It might also be unhappy of *role based* email addresses like `postmaster@example.com`, but then you will get a notification with a link to display the problematic email address(es).

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp's Omnivore spam filter throws lots of false positives. Unfortunately, they don't check their compliance questionnaires in a timely manner.

Sending an email to Compliance@mailchimp.com is your best bet.